# Will a video projector submerged in mineral oil still work?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, materials, design, heat-transfer

I’ve seen folks submerge computers in mineral oil to cool them- but would doing the same to a video projector profoundly throw off its internal optical aspects? I’m considering one of those small “hand held” projectors and having it project from inside an aquarium. I expect it to look cool but will it work?

Comment: At the moment this reads like you have an aquarium filled with mineral oil... Perhaps a diagram showing what you plan or do you mean a waterproof container for the projector and, if it is waterproof, will it need mineral oil?

Comment: No, mineral oil has a different index of refraction than air, and that difference will mess up the optics.  So tell us what you're really doing -- the fish in your aquarium will do less well in mineral oil than your optics.

Comment: This would be for a sculpture. I think the projector dropped into a tank of mineral oil is the correct image to have. I think the beam of light through the fluid maybe interesting as well as other potentially cool optical tricks. Especially if I use a projector built for near field focus I could potential project onto a screen also submerged or rear project on the glass of the tank itself etc. I can work out those details but I’m concerned if the internal optical array that produces the projection will be disabled by the thickness of the fluid.